# Trigger a google sheets function from PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets

I was looking everywhere, but there are simply no answers... maybe someone have gone through it already?
I need to call my custom function from Google Sheets on demand from PHP. Don't have any code, as I didn't find any reliable answers (most of questions about that are not getting any answer at all). Anybody knows how it works? From documentation, nothing about it. Or I couldn't find it.

Let's say I got some function called `getData()` in Google Sheets. I know I can trigger it from inside, but how can I trigger it from outside from PHP?

I can find a walk around for this, by triggering some function every minute or so, so it would check if it should get triggered in the first place, but that doesn't seem to be a good solution.

---

Because of 2 close votes and incompetent mods, I decided to edit my question, so everyone (even the ones who don't know anything about Google Sheets) would understand:

In Google Sheets you got script editor, where you can make your own function in JS. Using their libs to interact with their products, you can make a pretty complicated functions based od external data. I made a custom function called `getData()`, you can put it into a sheet like that: `=getData()` and it will work. You can also set a trigger to run that function periodically. But, I need to run it from `PHP` on demand, so the data would get triggered on refresh. So the question is ... how do I run a script editor function created in Google Sheets from `PHP`. As simple as that. Hopefully it helped to understand the question, as it was marked to be closed, because `Needs more focus;
Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.`. Have a nice day mods!

Comment: btw giving `-1` without a comment is against the rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need to run function from Apps script :

- create doPost or doGet functions [Link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- include getData() insidethe dopost/doget
- deploy script as web app
- with given url you can make http requests to trigger your function

Comment: oh thanx for a clue, I will check that out asap

Comment: that worked, thank you! funny that even mods didn't get what I meant, and it was like obvious.